# Generic Enum for bit fields

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I'd like to make it easier to work with bitfields instead of having to duplicate bitwise functions for each enum type I use. I came up with an interface which works well in C++ but I'm not sure how to build it in C# that is as performant as doing bitwise operations with an integer.

```
enum BitFlags : short
{
    F1 = 1 << 0,
    F2 = 1 << 1,
    F3 = 1 << 2,
};

class Flags<T> where T : System.Enum
{
    T val;

    public void SetFlag(T flag) => val |= flag;
    public void ClearFlag(T flag) => val & ~flag;
    public bool IsSet(T flag) => val & flag;
    // ... ClearAll(), IsExclusivelySet(), SetByBitNumber() 
}

// Flags<BitFlags> tst = new Flags<BitFlags>();
// tst.SetFlag(BitFlags.F1 | BitFlags.F3);
// tst.ClearFlag(BitFlags.F1);
// tst.IsSet(BitFlags.F3) returns true
// tst.IsSet(BitFlags.F1) return false
```

However, I get an error saying
`CS0019 Operator '|=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'`

Am I missing something simple or are there alternate performant designs?

Comment: Why make `Flags` as a template... use `BitFlags` insiead of `T` and everything will work

Comment: @MarcoBeninca because generally each context has a different enum like enum PlayerFlags { }, enum InternalState { } and for each enum I don't want to implement the bitwise operation each time. It's nice to have named enums and not a generic enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the language and runtime supports static interface operators (hopefully soon!), there is no great way to support `|`, `&` and `~` as a generic. For now, if you know (and validate!) that all of your enums are of a specific data size (i.e. `short` in the question), then you could perhaps use `Unsafe.As` as a lazy way of converting things without any boxing:

```cs
public void SetFlag(T flag)
    => Unsafe.As<T, short>(ref val) |= Unsafe.As<T, short>(ref flag);
```

but note that use of `Unsafe` **means any errors are on you**: if you're wrong (i.e. the `T` is not blittable to `short`): very bad things could happen.

Comment: That's kind of nice. I'm assuming I can assert the T value is at least the correct size (e.g. size of short) to make it a little bit safer.

Comment: @coderdave well, yes and no; you could try using a static type initializer for that purpose, but you *might* run into "beforefieldinit" timing problems (i.e. `static Flags() { /* your code here */ }`

Comment: @coderdave note: for the size part: `Unsafe.SizeOf` or `Enum.GetUnderlyingType`

Answer (score 3):

Operators cannot be used currently with generic types. This is coming as part of a .NET7/C#11 feature called `static virtual members in interfaces`. This is being added as part of a bigger effort for generic math as explained here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#generic-math-support

> You can add static abstract members in interfaces to **define interfaces that include overloadable operators**, other static members, and static properties.

In the meantime, you could probably leverage something like [the `BitArray` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=net-6.0) combined with casting the actual generic values to their underlying primitive types in your code.

Either that, or you'll have to migrate to C#11 preview and use one of the interfaces it provides, in particular [`IBitwiseOperators<TSelf,TOther,TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Fast forward to mid 2023. C#11 has been released... we now have `IBitwiseOperators`... but `Enum` doesn't derive from it... 

Answer (score 3):

With the current version of the language, you can use runtime code generation to implement these missing generic operators. Here’s how.

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Flags<T> where T : Enum
{
    T val;

    static readonly Func<T, T, T> or, andNot;
    // Static constructors only run once per type
    static Flags()
    {
        Type tEnum = typeof( T );
        ParameterExpression a = Expression.Parameter( tEnum, "a" );
        ParameterExpression b = Expression.Parameter( tEnum, "b" );

        Type tInt = tEnum.GetEnumUnderlyingType();
        Expression ai = Expression.Convert( a, tInt );
        Expression bi = Expression.Convert( b, tInt );

        or = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(
            Expression.Convert( Expression.Or( ai, bi ), tEnum ),
            a, b ).Compile();

        andNot = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(
            Expression.Convert( Expression.And( ai, Expression.Not( bi ) ), tEnum ),
            a, b ).Compile();
    }

    public void SetFlag( T flag ) => val = or( val, flag );
    public void ClearFlag( T flag ) => val = andNot( val, flag );
    public bool IsSet( T flag ) => val.HasFlag( flag );
}
```

Unlike the `Unsafe.As` this code should work with all enums regardless on their underlying integer type.

Comment: I'll have to profile that or perhaps do you know if runtime code generation will optimize that extra function calls down to the same version as a Int32 binary operator?

Comment: @coderdave The code of the compiled expressions is subject to the same optimizations as manually written C#, no overhead there. Calling that compiled expression has a cost of a virtual call. If you gonna call them in a loop, indirect branch predictor in CPU cores may actually help. You should definitely profile to find out how expensive are these indirect calls for your use case.